# Mutually recursive F# functions, typing issue

Tags: f#

Having trouble with this code:

```
  let subscribe (nm : NamespaceManager) (subName : string) (desc : TopicDescription)  : Async<SubscriptionDescription> =
    let rec first_create () =
      async {
        let! exists = desc |> exists nm
        if exists then return! (then_create_subscription () : Async<SubscriptionDescription>)
        try
          let beginCreate = nm.BeginCreateTopic : string * AsyncCallback * obj -> IAsyncResult
          logger.DebugFormat("creating topic '{0}'", desc)
          let! tdesc = Async.FromBeginEnd(desc.Path, beginCreate, nm.EndCreateTopic)
          return! first_create ()
        with | :? MessagingEntityAlreadyExistsException -> return! then_create_subscription () }
    and then_create_subscription ()  : Async<SubscriptionDescription> =
      async {
        let beginCreate = nm.BeginCreateSubscription : string * string * AsyncCallback * obj -> IAsyncResult
        return! Async.FromBeginEnd(desc.Path, subName, beginCreate, nm.EndCreateSubscription) }
    first_create ()
```

On line 5, it underlines `then_create_subscription () : Async<SubscriptionDescription>` stating:

> Type mismatch. Expecting a `Async<unit>` but given a `Async<SubscriptionDescription>` The type 'unit' does not match the type '`SubscriptionDescription`'

Exists looks like this:

```
  let exists (nm : NamespaceManager ) (desc : PathBasedEntity) = 
    async { return! Async.FromBeginEnd(desc.Path, nm.BeginTopicExists, nm.EndTopicExists) }
```

I want it to create the topic and then go on to create the subscription for it.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why recurse btw? Because the API says it's done, but isn't, when EndCreateTopic returns.

Comment: you need the `else` for that `if`

Comment: Was it that simple. Awesome, thanks Mauricio.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer  Should post that as an answer so that it can be marked as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There needs to be an `else` branch after if, otherwise the if is a statement, not an expression. The else is not implicit.